# How to resolve a type generic from the service collection based on the requesting type (similar to ILogger/Logger<TCategory>)?

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, service-provider

Lets say I have

```cs
public interface IService { }

public interface IService<TCategory> : IService { }

public class Service<TCategory> : IService<TCategory> { }
```

How do I get `ServiceCollection` to provide me `Service<MyClass>` and `Service<OtherClass>` when I resolve it like so?

```cs
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass(IService service) => Service = service;
    
    IService Service { get; } // Should be set to Service<MyClass>
}

public class OtherClass
{
    public OtherClass(IService service) => Service = service;
    
    IService Service { get; } // Should be set to Service<OtherClass>
}
```

I **DO NOT** want to register in the collection like so, such that it requires me to specify for the classes the specific type in the constructor.

```cs
serviceCollection.AddSingleton(typeof(IService<>), typeof(Service<>));

public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass(IService<MyClass> service) => Service = service;

    IService Service { get; }
}

public class OtherClass
{
    public OtherClass(IService<OtherClass> service) => Service = service;

    IService Service { get; }
}
```

I do not want to have to redundantly restate the class I'm already within as part of the type in the constructor. I basically want it to work similar/same as `ILogger`/`Logger<TCategory>`

I was hoping to find an extension method that accepted a delegate of `Func<IServiceProvider, type, object>`, but have had no luck.

EDIT:

I'll some additional context here to better illustrate. For instance, what I'm asking for is possible in other containers, such as SimpleInjector. This is how is it done.

```cs
container.RegisterConditional(typeof(ILogger),
                              _ => typeof(Logger<>).MakeGenericType(_.Consumer!.ImplementationType),
                              Lifestyle.Singleton,
                              _ => true);
```

I'm just trying to find the equivalent means of accomplishing this in Microsoft's `IServiceCollection`

Comment: You haven't explained what actually happens.

Comment: ILogger is not the same with ILogger<T>. One way to automatically register is to use reflection and to find all occurences of Service<TCategory> and register them with the DI that way.

Comment: @funatparties, you're missing the point. There are no existing instances of Service<T>. I want them created. I don't understand what you mean either by "ILogger is not the same with ILogger<T>". If MyClass ctor asks for ILogger, what I receive is Logger<MyClass>.

Comment: @aybe, what are you talking about? If I ask for IService, I get Service. But I want to ask for IService and get Service<MyClass>. How is that not clear?

Comment: @Ristogod if you try to resolve ILogger you get runtime exception. You need to resolve it with a strong type. And if you inject your interface with a strong type, let's say IService<T> then you can scan your constructors in your assemblies for all occurencies of IService<T>, then use the overload of IServiceCollection.AddTransient(Type, Type) to register them at runtime. This is all doable with reflection. This will help you get the generic type https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/how-to-examine-and-instantiate-generic-types-with-reflection.

Comment: If you still don't want to inject them with a strong type, then you should probably write some pre-build event which will replace IService with IService<T> in your code and then do the above. I can't think of other solution, with what the built-in DI offers.